# How to change color of Angular Formly description?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am working with angular formly.

**Here below is the Image of the Input Field and Its description.**
[image]

**What issue I am facing?**
Initially the description attribute have some default color but I want to ***change the color of description attribute*** once the input field have some value but I didn't get any solution till no for the same.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields" [options]="options" [form]="form"></formly-form>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFormOptions, FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-app-example',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model: any = {};
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'Input',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Input',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        description: 'Description',
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

HTML

```
<!-- NOTE ngClass > https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass -->
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <formly-form [ngClass]="{ 'value-change': isChange }" [model]="model" [fields]="fields" [options]="options" [form]="form"></formly-form>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFormOptions, FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-app-example',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  // NOTE change boolean
  isChange: boolean = false;
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model: any = {};
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'Input',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Input',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        description: 'Description',
        required: true,
        // NOTE change > https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/1225
        change: (field, $event) => {
          // NOTE you can add test here if you want specific change in your $event
          this.isChange = true;
        }
      },
    },
  ];
}
```

CSS

```
formly-form.value-change {
    ::ng-deep {
        your-description-label {
            color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I told I want it to change the color once the input field have some value. The solution which you have given will force to change it's color permanently.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @SatyamSingh I edit my previous response with more informations, I hope that would help you